# Virtual switch using SignalR server (Host my app)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I just created a chat App using signalR in C#(server) and JS(Client) and every thing is good and there is no problem when I run the server and client in my same device (localhost)

Now I want to run the client app out side my network , for example I want to make a chat with my friend who is living in another country using My app ,but I don't now how to do that and from where I need to start my search to do so.

Pleas if any one know how to do that or if any one know source that I can learn from it Help me

This is My signalR server Code

```
namespace PmmTcpListener
{
    public class PmmSignalRServer : IDisposable
    {

        #region Private Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// To be set in <see cref="Dispose(bool)"/> method
        /// </summary>
        private bool _disposedValue;
        public string SignalRwebAddress = "https://localhost:5050";
        public bool IsStarted = false;


        public bool cIsStarted = false;
        public string cSignalRwebAddress = "https://localhost:5050/pmmchat";
        private string PrevMessage = "";
        private string CrntMessage = "";

        private string ClientUrl = "";


        #endregion


        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// The main constructor for the class
        /// Doing instantiation for Sql Commands based on database type <see cref="DbTypes"/> 
        /// By the way the default selected one is type <see cref="DbTypes.mysql"/>
        /// </summary>
        public PmmSignalRServer()
        {
            //Initialize the Sql Commands
            //Sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand();
            //AlarmsCommand = new MySqlCommand();
            //SqlServerCmd = new SqlCommand();
            //SqlServerAlarmsCommand = new SqlCommand();
            //SqliteCmd = new SQLiteCommand();
            //SqliteAlarmsCommand = new SQLiteCommand();
        }

        #endregion


        #region MainFunctions


        /// <summary>
        /// To be set 
        /// </summary>
        //public void Start(string SRport = "https://localhost:5050")
        //{
        //  CreateWebHostBuilder().Build().Run();
        //}
        //private static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder() => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder().UseStartup<iStartup>().UseUrls("https://localhost:5050");



        /// <summary>
        /// To be set 
        /// </summary>
        public void StartServe(string SRport = "http://localhost:5050")
        {
            SignalRwebAddress = SRport;
            IsStarted = true;

            Thread Serverthread = new Thread(StartSeerverThread);
            Serverthread.Start();

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// To be set 
        /// </summary>
        private void StartSeerverThread()
        {
            try
            {
                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                    .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSignalR())
                    .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder =>
                {
                    //builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
                    //       .WithOrigins("http://localhost:59054")
                    //       .AllowCredentials();


                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
                })))

                    .Configure(app => app.UseRouting().UseCors("CorsPolicy").UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                    {
                        endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/PmmChat");
                    })
                    )

                    .UseUrls(SignalRwebAddress)
                    .ConfigureLogging(config =>
                    {
                        config.ClearProviders();
                    })
                    .Build()
                    .Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                PmmGlobFunctions.TrackThis(" StartServerThread : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// To be set 
        /// </summary>
        public void StartClient(string hubUrl = "https://localhost:5050")
        {
            SignalRwebAddress = hubUrl;
            cIsStarted = true;

            //ClientUrl

            ClientUrl = SignalRwebAddress.Replace(@"*", "localhost");

            ClientUrl = ClientUrl + @"/pmmchat";


            Thread thread = new Thread(StartClientThread);
            thread.Start();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// To be set 
        /// </summary>
        private void StartClientThread()
        {

            try
            {

                //IsStarted = true; .WithUrl(SignalRwebAddress+"/pmmchat")

                var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(ClientUrl).Build();

                connection.StartAsync().Wait();

                connection.InvokeCoreAsync("SendMessage", args: new[] { "PMM Users" }); // join the main group "PMM Users"

                while (cIsStarted)
                {
                    if (CrntMessage != PrevMessage)
                    {
                        connection.InvokeCoreAsync("SendMessage", args: new[] { "PmmServer", CrntMessage });
                        PrevMessage = CrntMessage;
                    }
                }


                connection.DisposeAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                PmmGlobFunctions.TrackThis(" StartClientThread : " + ex.Message);
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// To be set 
        /// </summary>
        public void StopClient()
        {
            cIsStarted = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// To be set 
        /// </summary>
        public void SendFromServer(string message)
        {
            CrntMessage = message;
            //connection.On("ReceiveMessage", (string userName, string message) =>
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(userName + " : " + message);
            //});
        }



        #endregion


        #region Implement Dispose

        /// <summary>
        /// if <paramref name="disposing"/> = true, The dispose method has been called
        /// by our code. Managed and unmanaged objects can be disposed
        /// if <paramref name="disposing"/> = false, The dispose method has been called
        /// by runtime finalizer. Unmanaged objects only should be disposed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">disposing value</param>
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // Dispose any managed objects
                    // ...
                }

                // Now disposed of any unmanaged objects
                // ...

                _disposedValue = true;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose method which implemented by <see cref="IDisposable"/>
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Calling override Dispose method to be used in implemented method
            Dispose(true);

            // Commented by Dr.Mahmoud
            //GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        #endregion 
    }

    public class ConnectionMapping<T>
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>> _connections =
            new Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>>();

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return _connections.Count;
            }
        }

        public void Add(T key, string connectionId)
        {
            lock (_connections)
            {
                HashSet<string> connections;
                if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
                {
                    connections = new HashSet<string>();
                    _connections.Add(key, connections);
                }

                lock (connections)
                {
                    connections.Add(connectionId);
                }
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetConnections(T key)
        {
            HashSet<string> connections;
            if (_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
            {
                return connections;
            }

            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }

        public void Remove(T key, string connectionId)
        {
            lock (_connections)
            {
                HashSet<string> connections;
                if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
                {
                    return;
                }

                lock (connections)
                {
                    connections.Remove(connectionId);

                    if (connections.Count == 0)
                    {
                        _connections.Remove(key);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
       
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {

        // My Work --> Mohannad 
        private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections = new ConnectionMapping<string>();

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public async Task SendMessageToClient(string user, string receiverConnectionId, string message)
        {
            foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(user))
            {
                await Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
            }
            // await Clients.Client(receiverConnectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }

        public async Task SendMessageUsers(string user, string[] receiverUsersIds, string message)
        {
            // here you need to set the list of Users
            await Clients.Users(receiverUsersIds).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }

        public async Task SendMessageOthers(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }


        public async Task SendMessageToUser(string user, string receiverConnectionId, string message)
        {
            await Clients.Client(receiverConnectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }

        public string GetConnectionId() => Context.ConnectionId;


        //public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        //{
        //    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        //    _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);

        //    return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        //}


        //public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        //{
        //    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        //    _connections.Remove(name, Context.ConnectionId);

        //    return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        //}


        // end Mohannad 

        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            // await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, PmmCommandReader.ReadCommand(message));
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }

        public Task SendMessageToCaller(string user, string message)
        {
            return Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }

        public Task SendMessageToGroup(string user, string message)
        {
            return Clients.Group("PMM Users").SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }

        public Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
        {
            return Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        }

        public Task LeaveGroup(string groupName)
        {
            return Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        }

    }


    //End of NameSpace
}
```

Comment: Where do you deploy your app? You could use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-overview

Comment: thank you so much for your help 
I will see the documentations